# Airflow v2.4.2 - New monthly DAG not running when scheduled

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I have the following in the dag.py file, this is a newly pushed to prod DAG, it should have run at 14UTC (9EST) it should have ran a few hours ago but it still hasn't run even thought in the UI is still saying it will run at 14UTC.

```
DAG_NAME = "revenue_monthly"
START_DATE = datetime(2023, 1, 12)
SCHEDULE_INTERVAL = "0 14 3 * *"

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': START_DATE,
    'depends_on_past': False
}


dag = DAG(DAG_NAME,
          default_args=default_args,
          schedule_interval=SCHEDULE_INTERVAL,
          doc_md=doc_md,
          max_active_runs=1,
          catchup=False,
          )
```

See picture below of the UI:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date and time you are seeing as `Next Run` is the `logical_date` which is the start of the data interval. With the current configuration the first DAGrun will be on data from `2023-02-03` to `2023-03-03` so the DAG will only actually be running on `2023-03-03` (the `Run After` date, you can see that one when you are viewing the DAG and hover over the schedule in the upper right corner:

[image: Where to find Run After date]

Assuming you want the DAG to do the run it would have done on `2023-02-03` (today) you can achieve that by backfilling one run, either by [manually backfilling](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#backfill). Or by using catchup=True with a start_date before `2023-01-03`:

```py
from airflow import DAG
from pendulum import datetime
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator

DAG_NAME = "revenue_monthly_1"
START_DATE = datetime(2023, 1, 1)
SCHEDULE_INTERVAL = "0 14 3 * *"
doc_md="documentation"

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': START_DATE,
    'depends_on_past': False
}

with DAG(
    DAG_NAME,
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=SCHEDULE_INTERVAL,
    doc_md=doc_md,
    max_active_runs=1,
    catchup=True,
) as dag:  

    t1 = EmptyOperator(task_id="t1")
```

gave me one run with the run id `scheduled__2023-01-03T14:00:00+00:00` and the next_run date interval `2023-02-03` to `2023-03-03` which will Run after `2023-03-03`.

[image: One run with catchup]

[This guide](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/scheduling-in-airflow) might help with terminology Airflow uses around schedules.

Comment: thanks for responding. This is still so confusing haha, but I think I get it. So the reason this didn't work is because I should have had the start_date before  '2023-01-03'  because then it would have triggered the dag to run on  '2023-02-03'?

Comment: Yes, exactly! The start_date signals "I want to include data this early" here, so it needs to be a whole month before the moment you want the DAG to actually run. And yeah, it takes a while to wrap your head around, haha. I often double check with the guide I linked to make sure I got the times right for all of the different schedule params.